# How does OpenSSH / NSS determine the address to use for a hostname with multiple DNS entries?

Tags: centos, ssh, nss

Suppose I have some device with multiple addresses like so (due to some combination of AD and VMWare NAT name resolution, but that's not germane):

```
[centos@localhost ~]$ getent hosts my-weird-AD-device.company.com
192.168.1.10   my-weird-AD-device.company.com
192.168.4.13   my-weird-AD-device.company.com
```

The address I have a route to is `192.168.1.10`, from a device on the same network segment as `192.168.4.13`.

If I try to SSH directly to `192.168.1.10`, everything works fine, but SSH'ing by *hostname* fails, because it tries to connect to `192.168.4.13`.

```
...
debug2: resolving "my-weird-ad-device.company.com" port 22
debug1: Connecting to my-weird-ad-device.company.com [192.168.4.13] port 22.
```

Can I control this behavior somehow, *from the SSH client*? I don't want to hardcode an IP into `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/hosts` as the working IP isn't static - I want to do this via name lookup if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does OpenSSH / NSS determine the address to use for a hostname
> with multiple DNS entries?

[getaddrinfo()](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_0_P1/ssh.c#L251)  the libc name resolver. Every address resolved is attempted, see [sshconnect.c](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_0_P1/sshconnect.c#L479)

`ssh_config` is sometimes useful as a crude name resolver because `HostName` real name keywords can go under `Host` or `Match` blocks. Problem is, I don't know of a way to modify these without duplicating the IP addresses. It is not powerful enough to rewrite names any way you like.

glibc allows influence of getaddrinfo sort order via gai.conf. This is not a ssh client config, it would affect glibc name resolution, and almost all software on the system.

Multiple DNS records of the same name, only one of which works to connect, is causing problems. Alter DNS such that there is a name that can be used for SSH. For example, renaming one of those zones such that the full name is unqiue, say `my-weird-AD-device.zone.company.com`. Or, add an additional short name to DNS for this host with only the correct IP, so `my-weird-AD-device-2`.

Comment: Yup, there it is. Thanks!